# Apache Flume not able to copy files from source to destination

Tags: hadoop, flume, hortonworks-data-platform, flume-ng, bigdata

I am executing Flume agent as user "root" where I want to copy my XML files which are kept at the location `/root/data-pipeline/input` to the destination location in the hdfs at location at `hdfs:///user/root/data_pipeline_demo/input..`

When I am executing the Flume agent as `flume-ng agent -c /etc/flume/conf -f /etc/flume/conf/flume.conf -n sandbox` ...It is not writing the files to the destination location & throwing the exception:

```
 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException
(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): 
 User: root is not allowed to impersonate root..
```

Where are things going wrong? Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the impersonation settings to match your HDFS setup. I am not familiar with your setup but almost sure that you don't use root user on Hadoop. If you change the settings to match your HDFS users it will start to work.

Comment: I even tried it multiple users i.e. ambari-qa or any custom user but still it threw the same error viz user ambari-qa is not allowed to impersonate ambari-qa......I configured Hadoop for impersonation by making following changes in core-site.xml <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.flume.groups</name>
     <value>users </value> </property>  <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.flume.hosts</name>
     <value>*</value> </property> ....but still failing & giving the same exception

Comment: Your source and target should not be the same, hdfs user can impersonate qa-user for example but hdfs to hdfs does not work.